# Why does calling Statement.close() not immediately release the ResultSet object created by a Statement object?

Tags: java, jdbc

From JDBC Spec

> Closing a Statement object will close and invalidate any instances of
>   ResultSet  produced by that Statement object. **The resources held by
>   the ResultSet object  may not be released until garbage collection
>   runs again**, so it is a good practice to  explicitly close ResultSet
>   objects when they are no longer needed.

- Does calling ResultSet.close() immediately release  a ResultSet object?
- Does calling Statement.close() immediately release  a Statement object?
- Calling Statement.close() releases the ResultSet objects created by a Statement object, so why does it not immediately release the ResultSet object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Javadoc of [`Statement.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close()) (*emphasis* mine):

> *Releases this `Statement` object's database and JDBC resources
>   immediately* instead of waiting for this to happen when it is
>   automatically closed. It is generally good practice to release
>   resources as soon as you are finished with them to avoid tying up
>   database resources.
>
> Calling the method close on a `Statement` object that is already closed
>   has no effect.
>
> **Note:** *When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object,
>   if one exists, is also closed.*

Here, the Javadoc states that closing a `Statement` *immediately* releases its resources *and* also closes its current `ResultSet`.

And the Javadoc of [`ResultSet.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close()) (*emphasis* mine):

> *Releases this `ResultSet` object's database and JDBC resources
>   immediately* instead of waiting for this to happen when it is
>   automatically closed.
>
> The closing of a `ResultSet` object does **not** close the `Blob`, `Clob` or
>   `NClob` objects created by the `ResultSet`. `Blob`, `Clob` or `NClob` objects
>   remain valid for at least the duration of the transaction in which
>   they are created, unless their free method is invoked.
>
> When a `ResultSet` is closed, any `ResultSetMetaData` instances that were
>   created by calling the `getMetaData` method remain accessible.
>
> **Note:** A `ResultSet` object is automatically closed by the `Statement`
>   object that generated it when that `Statement` object is closed,
>   re-executed, or is used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of
>   multiple results.
>
> Calling the method close on a `ResultSet` object that is already closed
>   is a no-op.

This Javadoc states that closing a `ResultSet` will release its resources *immediately* as well. And, as stated above, calling `Statement.close()` will also close the `ResultSet`.

The note also states that only one `ResultSet` can be open per `Statement` at any given time. The previous `ResultSet` will be closed automatically if you make another request (or if any of the other conditions, as stated, are met).

*Note: All Javadoc quotes and links are for Java 10.*

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is immediately released according to [ResultSet SE 8 #close()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#close--)

The same for [Statement SE 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--)

Also the [ResultSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed.

> A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of multiple results.

Answer (score 1):

Note on closing JDBC objects.

As of Java SE 7 one can use try-with-resources to manage the JDBC objects. The `Connection`, `Statement`, `ResultSet`, `RowSet` intefaces extend `java.lang.AutoCloseable`. The try-with-resources statement ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement (irrespective of how the code within the block completes).

Here is some example Java and JDBC code - note the statement and resultset are created within the try-with-resources block.

```
public void printAllBooks()
        throws SQLException {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM book_table";
    try(Statement stmnt = conn.createStatement(); // conn is the Connection object
        ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Id: " + rs.getString("book_id") +
                    " Author: " + rs.getString("author") +
                    " Title: " + rs.getString("title"));
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- One can declare one or more resources within a try-with-resources
  statement.
- A try-with-resources statement can have optional catch and/or finally blocks. Any catch or finally block is run after the resources declared are closed.
- When the block of code that directly follows try-with-resources terminates, either normally or because of an exception, the close() methods of the `Statement` and `ResultSet` are automatically called in the *opposite order* of their creation.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of that sentence. Depending on the usage pattern of statements in an application, the `Statement` object may live a lot longer than the `ResultSet` produced by that statement. So, if you don't explicitly close the `ResultSet` as soon as you are done with it, it will continue to be open and hold resources until you close the statement or execute another query on that statement object, or until the garbage collector can collect the result set, which assumes the statement doesn't hold a strong reference to the result set (and that is very much an implementation specific detail).

In other words, while a statement `close()` will close the result set and its resources immediately, you shouldn't rely on that behavior and instead close the result set as soon as possible.

Disclaimer: I'm a member of the JDBC expert group of JSR-221

Comment: Thanks. "a statement close() will close the result set and its resources immediately". Does a statement's close() immediately close and release its resultset objects and the resources used by its resultset objects?

Comment: @Tim Yes, I'm not sure why you rephrase what I say as a question. A statement close closes the result set - if any - and a result set close will release its resources. The JDBC specification and API documentation is pretty clear on this.

Comment: Because after calling statement.close(), "The resources held by the ResultSet object may not be released until garbage collection runs again". So i guess what the quote means is that statement.close() release its resultset objects immediately, but leave the resources used by its resultset objects to be released by garbage collector later. Do I misunderstand it?